# call didFailWithError: of CLLocationManager delegate on purpose

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation

I want to test something and want to provoke an error on purpose, so this delegate function gets fired.

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // handle error
}
```

anyone has a tip how to achieve this? (Turning off perimssions does not work).

Comment: turning off internet might help :) or running the code with background capability "Location updated" turned off might help as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting **CLLocationManager** object to *nil* and this method will get fired.

Note:- This will stop updating locations and your **didupdatelocations** method will not get called either.

Comment: Im really stupid, I had another change in my code. Sorry, not working.